# How do you disable the alt+ mouse wheel scroll = moving frames in timeline. I end up accidentaly keying on the wrong frame with this

Tags: animation, timeline, mouse

How do you disable the alt+ mouse wheel scroll = moving frames in timeline. I end up accidentaly keying on the wrong frame with this.

Comment: Any entry for it under Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Frames? If so, just uncheck the entry to disable it.

Comment: As John says, in the Preferences > Keymap > Name, type Frame Offset and check the shortcut

Comment: Works like a charm. Had to disable the frame offset. Thanks good people of the internet